# Launching an Activity from listview

Tags: android, android-listview

**Hello**

### I am trying to launch an activity onclick of an item in listview

- I am using Bean class (Names.java) for this
- Here are my classes

---

**Names.java**

```
public class Names implements Serializable{

    private String Name;

    public void setName(String name){
        this.Name=name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return Name;
    }

}
```

**NewProfile.java**

```
public class NewProfile extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.new_profile);

        Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
        TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.NewTextView);

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textStyle="italic|bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**new_profile.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/NewTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {


    ArrayList<Names> AL=new ArrayList<Names>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Names obj1=new Names();
        obj1.setName("Sam");
        AL.add(obj1);

        Names obj2=new Names();
        obj2.setName("carl");
        AL.add(obj2);




        ListView LV=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,R.id.textView1,AL);
        LV.setAdapter(adapter);
        LV.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Bundle B=new Bundle();
            TextView TV=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


            if(position==0){


            }   
        }

}
```

---

MainActivity class is incomplete ..... i am trying to fill the parts of this class

**anyIdeas,**

*Thanks*

Comment: So any exception occured?

Comment: I am trying to know how to use the bean class in listview..... apparently im having difficulty in filling few code parts of MainActivity :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An activity has the methods

```
startActivity(Intent)
startActivityForResult(Intent, requestCode)
```

As the names suggests, the second one is used, if you want to get some sort of data back to you first activity.

Now in your **onClick()** methode:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, NewProfile.class);
startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_SOMETHING);
```

You can pack information in your Intent, if you need them in your second activity like this:

```
int important = 10;
i.putExtra(EXTRA_IMPORTANT_INT, important);
```

To get to this information in your **NewProfile activity** you need to get the Intent: (e.g. in your onCreate())

```
int important = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_IMPORTANT_INT, 0);
```

EXTRA_IMPORTAN_INT is a String constant, REQUEST_SOMETHING is a int constant, which should be unique.

If you used the second methode and want to quit the started activity with a result:

```
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra(EXTRA_NEW_VALUE, something);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
finish();
```

After the finish() is called, the starting activity's **[onActivityResult(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29)** will be called.

Answer (score 0):

You can start new activity using following code..write your logic as per your requirement

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Intent intent=new Intent(CURRENT_ACTIVITY.this,NEW_ACTIVITY.class);
    startActivity(intent); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set the your ListView `LV` set the `setOnItemClickListener(this)` and you should continue with this.

```
setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), YourNextActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);


            }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register setOnItemClickListener event on the ListView's object. In this way you can start new Activity:

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ThisActivity.this, That_Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent); 
            }
        } );
```

And if you want to pass some data to another activity you can use.

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ThisActivity.this, That_Activity.class);
    //If you want to pass some data use.
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putInt("KeyGoesHere", intValue);
    intent.putExtras(extras); 
    startActivity(intent);


            }
        } );
```